# Browser GUI for local desktop application?

Tags: user-interface, browser, desktop-application

So far I have only been developing desktop applications using C++ or C#.

Now I am considering building a local standalone application using a browser GUI. The application would be similar to something I could e.g. build with C#. It should have local database access and offer some limited image editing (line drawing, polygon filling) and user defined, clickable graphical elements (basically polygons the user draws).

The application should *not* be web or server based. The application will also not be very complex.

The main thought behind this is to have the GUI be OS independent and as platform independent as possible.

Is that feasible? Or should I go about something as Swing, SWT or Java FX (which I have just read about)?

What programming language should I use for the application (Java, Python, ...)?

Are there toolkits for a programming language you recommend that offer an abstraction layer from OS specific stuff like file system handling?

Are there toolkits or tools that would help me in creating the browser GUI?

Comment: Have you considered Chrome Apps (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)? Not platform independent as you're reliant on the Google Chrome web browser but will work on Win, Mac & Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use c++ for this :) and for your GUI use OpenGL, and then you can use glut... You can take a look at OpenGL superbible book, it mostly about 3D drawing, but there is also something about gui... and it comes with examples for linux, windows, mac... basicly it is OS independent...

Comment: Sorry, but I thought it would be clear from what I wrote that I don't want to use C++ or C#. OpenGL also definitely is not what I want to use to create the UI. I want a solution that is as platform independent as possible. I may even turn it into a web based application somewhere in the future (this is just a maybe though).